# Shrinking Raspberry Pi SD .img via Ubuntu Server (cli)

Tags: debian, command-line, disk-image

I installed Raspbian to a 16 GB card and expanded the filesystem. When I made a `dd` backup of the card, the .img file output was ~16 GB. Most of it is unused space in the ext4 partition—I'm only using like 2.5 GB in that partition. (There are two partitions—the first is FAT for boot and the second is ext4 for rootfs.) I'd like to shrink the backup.img file which resides on an Ubuntu 16.04 Sever installation (no GUI) so that I can restore the image to a card of smaller size (say 8GB for example).

So far, I have mounted the ext4 partition to `/dev/loop0` by using the offset value provided to me by `fdisk -l backup.img`. Then I used `e2fsck -f /dev/loop0` and then `resize2fs -M /dev/loop0` which appeared to shrink the ext4 fs... am I on the right track? I feel like `parted` might be next, but I have *no* experience with it.

**How do I accomplish this using only cli tools?**

---

Update:

Here is the output from running `fdisk -l backup.img`:

```
Disk backup.img: 14.9 GiB, 15931539456 bytes, 31116288 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x79d38e92

Device        Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
backup.img1 *      8192   124927   116736   57M  e W95 FAT16 (LBA)
backup.img2      124928 31116287 30991360 14.8G 83 Linux
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm you are in the right track shrinking that filesystem; fdisk/parted is next. The tricky part is getting it right next to the size of the new filesystem,do your math or leak a hundred KB more just to be safe. You can adjust it later on the new card if need be.

The order is normally: umount, resize, fdisk/parted, partprobe, fsck, and mount to check all is ok. As the partition you are resizing is less than 2T, you can use either `fdisk` or `parted`.

The resize process has to come first, as you won't be able to shrink the partition reliably while the filesystem still claims the space you need to reclaim. After you need to shrink the partition once again for consistency, and for not having the remaining space you want to rid off "booked" for use. The filesystem as to come last to make the filesystem structure consistent with the new size.

I will leave these RH articles. It is missing the `partprobe`, as the new partition size is not always recognised immediately or by older kernels.

[How to Shrink an ext2/3/4 File system with resize2fs](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1196333)

[How to Resize a Partition using fdisk](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1190213)

Your missing steps are:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/loop
p     - to check for partition number (probably 2)
d     - to delete
2     - partition 2
n     - new partition
p     - primary
ENTER - default beginning
+new size -  smaller card size
w      - write it

sudo partprobe /dev/loop
```

To finish it off, you umount the image file; as the extra size is no longer marked as used both by the filesystem and the partition size in your file image, the operation system won't try to use that space. So it can be  truncated safely to the intended size:

```
truncate -s 8GB fileName
```

To use the appropriate sizes, as I am lazy, I would shring the filesystem to something less than what I need (i.e. size of new partition - 400k, and then expand it again after I shrink the partition), and would create the partition with the needed size (8GB-2048(2K) for possible 1st partition padding-minus the size of the 1st partition). Not much math involved.

For calculating it properly, please do have a look:

[How To Resize ext3 Partitions Without Losing Data](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_resizing_ext3_partitions)

Comment: Won't I still need to `truncate` the backup.img file after everything? I am trying to get an understanding of the entire process. I have already done a lot of Googling, including finding those articles you linked to, but I don't presently have the confidence that comes from understanding these tools and their purposes.

Comment: Yes, obviously...nevertheless if you dd it after all these operation without truncating, the job is already done. If you want to understand it better, do a copy of the file, and perform the process. If anything goes wrong, you just need to copy it over and start the process again.

Comment: Ok, so how about that last step? How does truncating work? Will you please add that to your answer?

Comment: I guess what I meant was this: how do I truncate the backup.img so that it is the minimum size of the partitions and filesystems inside it?

Comment: No, I mean... how do I calculate that / what value do I use? Do I use the final End sector from the last partition returned by `fdisk -l backup.img` or do I use that sector +1 byte or what?

Comment: Added a little more to the answer, and a link.

Comment: The padding can be between 1024 to 4096, only digging more about it in the image with the output of `fdisk -l /dev/loop`

Comment: It worked (and I used `parted` > `resizepart` instead of `fdisk`), but I am still not clear about how to determine the minimum byte position for resizing the partition and also for the `truncate` command. How do I determine what is safe other than by trial and error? In my test, I did this (broken into multiple comments here): `sudo fdisk -l backup.img` which produced two lines of 512B sectors for the two partitions. The start value for the second one is what I desired and it was 124928. Then I ran `losetup -f`, which output `/dev/loop0`

Comment: Would you please add the output of fdisk to your question?

Comment: Then I ran `sudo losetup -o $((512*124928)) $(losetup -f) backup.img` Then `sudo e2fsck -f /dev/loop0` then `sudo resize2fs -M /dev/loop0` which reported success with a value in 4KiB blocks, which I converted to bytes, and for this comment, I'll refer to `$end` because I don't remember the exact value. I then ran `sudo parted /dev/loop0` and in interactive mode ran `resizepart 1` then the value of `$end` + (1024*1024) and `quit`. I then ran `sync` and `sudo partprobe /dev/loop0` before `sudo losetup -d /dev/loop0`.

Comment: I am afraid I got lost. Will have a look at it later on.

Comment: Then I ran `truncate -s` with the previous value + the end value of the first partition in bytes + (1024*1024). Updating question with `fdisk` output.

Comment: Sorry I'm unable to write more structured commands in the comments. I know it's a bit zany. Basically if the output of `resize2fs -M /dev/loop0` = (x / 4096), then I used x + (1024 * 1024) for `parted` and x + (124927 * 512) + (1024 * 1024 * 2) for `truncate`.

Comment: Were you able to take another look at it?

Comment: With the fdisk output should be easier. I am not able to answer to you today, but in the meantime will be thinking how to convey it in an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

What about using the [Automatic RPi Image Downsizer](https://github.com/SirLagz/RaspberryPi-ImgAutoSizer/blob/master/autosizer.sh)?

You can as well take a look at the code to see what is going on.

```
if [[ ! $(whoami) =~ "root" ]]; then
echo ""
echo "**********************************"
echo "*** This should be run as root ***"
echo "**********************************"
echo ""
exit
fi

if [[ -z $1 ]]; then
echo "Usage: ./autosizer.sh "
exit
fi

if [[ ! -e $1 || ! $(file $1) =~ "x86" ]]; then
echo "Error : Not an image file, or file doesn't exist"
exit
fi

partinfo=`parted -m $1 unit B print`
partnumber=`echo "$partinfo" | grep ext4 | awk -F: ' { print $1 } '`
partstart=`echo "$partinfo" | grep ext4 | awk -F: ' { print substr($2,0,length($2)-1) } '`
loopback=`losetup -f --show -o $partstart $1`
e2fsck -f $loopback
minsize=`resize2fs -P $loopback | awk -F': ' ' { print $2 } '`
minsize=`echo $minsize+1000 | bc`
resize2fs -p $loopback $minsize
sleep 1
losetup -d $loopback
partnewsize=`echo "$minsize * 4096" | bc`
newpartend=`echo "$partstart + $partnewsize" | bc`
part1=`parted $1 rm 2`
part2=`parted $1 unit B mkpart primary $partstart $newpartend`
endresult=`parted -m $1 unit B print free | tail -1 | awk -F: ' { print substr($2,0,length($2)-1) } '`
truncate -s $endresult $1
```

Comment: I asked how to go about accomplishing my goal because I want to understand the process.

Comment: Well the steps in the script are self explanatory and a good way to learn independently (autodidactic approach), which at the end of the day, is what will reside in your memory for a longer period of time.

Comment: I realize that I could read every manpage for every command installed and that would sort my issue, but that's why I'm posting on SE: to get help from others instead of doing that or instead of trial/error. I'm looking for **instruction / teaching**. I appreciate that you Googled for me and copy-pasted.

Comment: I respect your approach.